# Firestore reference fields - should it not exist if there is no reference?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app where users have a `currentActivity` field that references an `Activity`.

ex:

```
User
  name: My Name
  currentActivity: activities/g07JPaTfuqSXgRG7tqVs
```

However, once the user is no longer doing that activity, should I remove that field from the User object, or is there a way to set it to NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to either:

- Totally delete the field, or;
- Set the field to `null`, or;
- Set the field to another value like an empty string.

The last two cases have an advantage over the first one: you can query it with the not equal (`!=`) operator to return documents where the `currentActivity` field exists and does not match null or does not match the empty string (in other words the users with an activity).

You cannot do the same query with the first approach (field deletion) because you cannot query on a field that does not exists.

Note that the doc on the [not equal operator in queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_) indicates that "you cannot use the not equal (`!=`) operator with `null` because `x != null` evaluates to `undefined`" but actually `usersRef.where('currentActivity', '!=', null).get();` does work correctly: you get all the docs with a currentActivity field that is different of `null`.

More details in the following other Firestore documentation sections:

- [Firestore Data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types)
- [Deleting fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields)

Comment: Thanks!  I think I will use the 3rd option and use a empty string :D